# Lightroom tip to show something nearly b/w on a b/w background better

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing

I've took the following picture today:[image]

On the pole sits a bird, I would like to make the bird a bit more obvious.
Normaly I can do this with boosting color or contrast. But it doesn't really work that time.

I also tried to make the pole bigger in photoshop, but it looks strange.

What would you do to get the attention to the bird?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using an 18-55 kit lens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem open to the idea of Photoshopping, I would work on the bird's background:

1. Create a layer for the entire tree-lined background and houses. Boost it so you can see some minor details in the trees.
2. Then clone-stamp out the houses directly behind the bird. The bird is competing for the viewer's attention with the houses behind it. So eliminate the competition.
3. To further reduce the competition, consider applying a *slight* Gaussian filter over the tree-line background, and a slight bit more of a filter over the mountain and clouds, to simulate a tiny bit shallower depth of field. That will help isolate the foreground from the background.

However, you have to recognize that the bird is a small part of the foreground, not tonally distinct from the entire image. And most importantly, is not sharp — it's not the subject in most focus. Ultimately, if the bird was your *intended* subject of interest, Photoshop can't really fix fundamental composition issues. But if you're just trying to make the bird pop a little, I'd work on isolating it from the background.

Comment: Yeah, I know I failed a bit in compositing. Sadly I just noticed now in post. I will follow your advice and make it forest. Thank you!

Comment: Alternative thought: raise the water horizon until it’s over the bird. Mess with the water shading as necessary.